# can't run flutter run command on real device

Tags: android, flutter, macos, adb

I want to run **flutter run** on real device but can't, even though before installing java and making release versions for other applications there was no problem. If the project is run on android emulator or **flutter build apk** there is no problem. Below is the error message I get when running the **flutter run** command

> ayub@192 md5creator % flutter run
>
> Launching lib/main.dart on SM A325F in debug mode...
>
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             37.2s
>
> ✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
>
> - daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
> - daemon started successfully
>
> Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...                659ms
>
> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
>
> Performing Streamed Install
>
> adb: failed to install /Users/ayub/Documents/flutter_projects/md5creator/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:
>
> Uninstalling old version...
>
> adb uninstall failed: ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
>
> - daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> ADB server didn't ACK
>
> Full server startup log: /var/folders/gq/r6xq634s0bg5ys8knzlk3ltw0000gn/T//adb.501.log
>
> Server had pid: 2203
>
> --- adb starting (pid 2203) ---
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26552 main.cpp:63] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26552 main.cpp:63] Version 33.0.2-8557947
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26552 main.cpp:63] Installed as /Users/ayub/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26552 main.cpp:63]
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26562 usb_osx.cpp:316] reported max packet size for RR8R808KMLN is 512
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26552 auth.cpp:417] adb_auth_init...
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26552 auth.cpp:152] loaded new key from '/Users/ayub/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint
>
> BD70E3110DFE2023B4826351A71B08B2432B690E0643AC28
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26588 transport.cpp:304] RR8R808KMLN: write thread spawning
>
> adb I 08-12 17:00:14  2203 26587 transport.cpp:332] RR8R808KMLN: read thread spawning
>
> - failed to start daemon
>
> adb: cannot connect to daemon
>
> Command: /Users/ayub/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s RR8R808KMLN uninstall com.example.md5creator
>
> Error: Uninstalling old version failed.
>
> Error launching application on SM A325F.

Comment: Is the existing app on your phone by any chance an installed app?

Comment: @Denzel the app doesn't exist on the phone

Comment: try flutter clean

Comment: @HKN I have tried but it's the same

Comment: Can you show the output of 'flutter devices' when your device is plugged?

Comment: @batuhand i get error, Unable to run "adb", check your Android SDK installation and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
environment variable: /Users/ayub/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: Doe your device has enough space ?

Comment: @HardikMehta of course, more than 20GB

Comment: @MeeMihoyo : Please goto developer options and  disable usb debugging and enable it again

Comment: @HardikMehta I've tried but it's the same

Comment: @MeeMihoyo :   Try to invalidate caches and restart for android studio

Comment: Problems with adb on MacOS are pretty frequent the last months. You can try to restart adb on command-line `adb kill-server´. I assume your Mac has an M1/M2 CPU? If yes this may be a problem with Rosetta (one program is running natively the other inside Rosetta).

Comment: @HardikMehta I've tried but it's the same

Comment: @Robert , i get error, cannot connect to daemon at tcp:5037: Connection refused

Comment: ADB on the host side is separated into two processes: the one is the adb executable you execute to send the command and the other is a persistent server/daemon that is started once and the keep listening for commands from the client on TCP port 5037. That server is not reachable by the command-line adb versions thus adb does not work.     regarding the "why" this daemon is not there I can't help you, as I don't work with Android + MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, go to Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK and check if the required sdk packages are installed.

[image]

Comment: i have installed the sdk according to the real device but its the same